# Custom Layout Views for a Record with relationship details

Tags: custom-object, custom-view, metadata-relationship

Is it possible to create custom views for a particular record that will include details on related fields?

For example, I have a `Student` object and a `Course` object, and then I have a `StudentCourseRelationship` object that represents a Student having a relationship with a Course. This Relationship Object has some fields like `completed` which is a boolean.

With this data, I would like to create a view related to the student that would display:

- Student Information (all my custom fields)
- A list of the student's StudentCourseRelationships where `completed==true`
- A list of the student's StudentCourseRelationships where `completed==false`

In simpler terms, StudentCourseRelationship is suppose to represent any Course a Student has enrolled in at one point or another, and in the Student View, I want to display both a list of the student's completed courses and a list of the student's incomplete courses.

Is this possible? Everything I research related to custom views leads to a custom object's `Page Layout` (single record) or creating a custom `List View` (single object).

EDIT: A more complicated example of where I will need to use such a `Layout View`:

I have an `Advisor` object. 
I have a `Student` object that has a `Gender` look up field and an `Advisor` look up field. 
I have a `Match` field that has look up fields to `Student` and `Career`.

Advisor --> Student
Gender --> Student
Student --> Match <-- Career

How could I create a view/report that, for a single Advisor Record would show me:

```
How many times each `Career` record has been "Matched" to a `Student`, broken down by the student's gender?

i.e. 
Accounting: 10 Matches to Male Students, 30 Matches to Female Students
IT: 30 Matches to Female Students, 10 Matches to Male Students
```

Is the only possible way to do this through a Visual Force page? Could this be done through Reports (grouped reports don't seem to work as I originally expected)?

Comment: As long as you have a Parent/Child relationship between your objects, you can achieve it using [Filter Related Lists without Code](https://douglascayers.com/2015/11/18/salesforce-filter-related-lists-without-code/).

Comment: This seems like a way to filter lists automatically, not a custom view for a record's related objects...

Comment: I thought you were looking for that, isn't it? *I want to display both a list of the student's completed courses and a list of the student's incomplete courses*

Comment: `..in the Student View, I want to display both a list of the Student's Completed Courses.....` i.e., when I click on a Student Record, I would like to see those lists within that record's view.

Comment: And that's what the blog helps to achieve. The example there is with Account/Contact relationship, but is applicable to any Parent/Child relationship. So as long as you have the `Student` and `StudentCourseRelationship` as Parent/Child (which seems you have set it that way), you can achieve it the way explained in the blog.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for a sloppy hack (i.e. create 2 extra lookup fields to represent the two different states of the main look up field <yikes>). I'm looking for a solid, standard practice of representing such data. My example was a very simplistic version of what I need to do, and not all of my scenarios for implementing this will be based off of two states (true/false.) I was looking for a more programmable, dynamic way to display relational data more than 1 level deep. Thanks though

Comment: There's no standard practice to represent the data that you are looking for. If you cannot achieve what you want to implement with out of the box provided/available ways, your only option is to create custom pages either using VF page or Lightning Aura/Web Components.

Comment: My whole question was whether or not this is possible... so VisualForce pages are my answer? Thanks

Comment: I added the contents from comments, as an answer to your question.

Comment: I updated my question for a more complicated example of my situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

> My whole question was whether or not this is possible... so VisualForce pages are my answer?

This is possible, but using some customization. At times when we exhaust the options what are available to us out of the box, we could utilize the customization route.

In your case, you can either utilize the configuration only route if you are only looking for a filtered list view as mentioned in [Filter Related Lists without Code](https://douglascayers.com/2015/11/18/salesforce-filter-related-lists-without-code/) by [@Doug Ayers](https://twitter.com/DouglasCAyers).

OR

If you don't want to utilize the option as in the link, your options depending on the view you are in Classic vs. Lightning, are to create custom screens using:

- Visualforce pages
- Lightning Aura Component
- Lightning Web Component

Comment: I was able to figure out that Visualforce Pages, Aura Components, and Web Components can be added to a record's `Page Layout`, so thanks for that tip. Now, if I'm on a certain `Student` record, can you set up your VF Page or Component to "take in" the current Student record? Like, can you pass the current student record (or Id) to the component so that you can have the component be custom for that user? Sorry for my unfamiliarity to SF, it's all new to me.

Comment: I guess, is a Lightning Component or a VF Page better equipped to take in variables?

Comment: @BlondeSwan Yes you can. As an example you can have interface say `force:hasRecordId` on an aura component which directs the component that it has a record id, and use that component on the record page. I will definitely recommend to take some trailhead for more information. That’s a good place to get started on this topic.